# sql program with Group by 2 attributes and 1 condition (Import)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a text file that contains Candy issued data.
File contains customer id, issue date, candy name.

C1,2014-01-01,Candy1
C1,2014-01-02,Candy2
C2,2002-06-01,Candy2
C1,2014-01-02,Candy3
C2,2002-06-01,Candy3

I am trying to figure out how can I write a program that creates a list of pairs of candies which were issued together i.e. issued to the same customer on the same day at least twenty-five different times.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
--create a table to hold our data
create table CandySales
(
    CustomerId nchar(2)
    , SaleDate Date
    , CandyId nvarchar(10)
)

--upload the data from the csv
bulk insert CandySales 
from 'c:\temp\myCsv.csv' 
with (fieldterminator = ',', rowterminator = '\n')

--query the data
;with cte as 
(
    select customerId, candyId, saleDate 
    from CandySales 
    group by customerId, candyId, saleDate 
    having COUNT(1) >= 25
)
select distinct 
  a.CandyId Item1
, b.CandyId Item2
from cte a
inner join cte b
on a.CandyId > b.CandyId
and a.SaleDate = b.SaleDate
and a.CustomerId = b.CustomerId
```

**Explanation of Query**

- The cte creates a list of all candies which have had 25 or more sales to the same customer on the same day.
- include `distinct` as we may have the same pair returned for multiple dates/customers; we only want each pair once.
- `on a.CandyId > b.CandyId` is used as we want to ensure the pair contains different candies from one another.  We use `>` instead of `!=` to avoid getting the same pair with `item1` and `item2` reversed.
- we then join on sale date and customer date as we want items which were sold to the same customer on the same day.

Comment: Awesome, thanks alot. But I have 1 question, CandyId you used above is actually varchar, so can we use on a.CandyId > b.CandyId in the join condition?